# How can I remove the frame of subplots from behind colour bars?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have different subplots sharing x axis. I have already set spines off for all the plots, but when I draw some bars using axvspan the 'ghost' of the plots' spines appear behing the coloured areas.

Anyone would like to suggest a solution to get rid the bars of the 'ghost lines'?

Thanks in advance

```
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5, ax6, ax7) = plt.subplots(7, sharex=True,subplot_kw={'clip_on':False})
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)


axes = [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5, ax6, ax7]

for ax in axes:
    ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)

ax1.plot(data1['age'], data1['Pb'], linewidth=0.8, c='black')
ax1.set_ylabel('Pb',c='black')
ax1.spines['left'].set_visible(True)
ax1.spines['left'].set_bounds(75, 25)
ax1.tick_params(labelbottom=False, bottom=False)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', color='black', labelcolor='black')
...
for ax in axes:
     ax.axvspan(7600, 7500, alpha=0.2, color='red')
     ax.axvspan(7500, 7200, alpha=0.2, color='blue')
     ax.axvspan(7200, 7000, alpha=0.2, color='red')
     ax.axvspan(7000, 6600, alpha=0.2, color='blue')
     ax.axvspan(6600, 6300, alpha=0.2, color='red')
     ax.axvspan(6300, 6000, alpha=0.2, color='blue')
     ax.axvspan(6000, 5800, alpha=0.2, color='red')
     ax.axvspan(2000, 0, alpha=0.2, color='grey')

plt.xlabel('age bp')
plt.show()
```

[grey, red and blue bars show the spines of the plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwpbX.png)

Comment: This looks like a bug with the alpha blending of the spine & vspan (in as much as there should not be any since the spine is set to invisible). It is unclear to me if the issue is with matplotlib or the backend. Could you check if the problem persists if you use a different [backend](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/backends.html)? Also, try saving to a different file format.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It actually worked saving the plot as .pdf file. Thanks!